# Is "each" supposed to refer to a singular subject?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Usually "each" is used to refer to every member in the group, so it is followed by a singular verb like:

> Each student and teacher knows that exams are.....
>
> Each of the buildings is surrounded by high metal fencing.

Now I am not sure how the first sentence in the following examples is wrong.

> **Wrong**: They understand the **personality** of each of their children
>
> **Correct**: They understand the **personalities** of each of their children
>
> **Wrong**: There were four rooms, each with a wonderful **view** of the garden
>
> **Correct**: There were four rooms, each with wonderful **views** of the garden.
>   This example was copied from [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/each)

**Would you please explain it to me?**

Comment: Who says those answers were wrong? (Give the source).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Some examples are copied from Cambridge and all started when a British teacher told me "personalities" not personality!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wrong: They understand the personality of each of their children

Not wrong.

> Correct: They understand the personalities of each of their children

Wrong, in the most commonplace sense. It implies the children are schizophrenic.

> Wrong: There were four rooms, each with a wonderful view of the garden

Not wrong.

> Correct: There were four rooms, each with wonderful views of the garden.

Correct, since a room can have many wonderful views.

*The word "each" acts as a singular.* So "each student has a notebook". There is a one-to-one correspondence, you shouldn't say "notebooks" simply because there are multiple students.

Comment: I'm unsure what a grammarian would say, but as a native speaker, I agree with this, as otherwise you end up with ambiguous terms as @Sam says. Do the children have multiple personalities? (No) Are there multiple views of the garden from each room? (No). It would only be personalities if you omitted the *each* :- *They understand the personalities of their children*.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Cambridge E.D.[enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/each-or-every)
Each or every?
We use each to refer to **individual** things in a group or a list of two or more things. It is often similar in meaning to every.

**Plurals**! The combination of Plurals and singular in each sentence.

Each student and teacher knows that exams are..... **Singular + Singular**

Each of the buildings is surrounded by high metal fencing. **Plural + Plural** However this can be split down as each individual building in the group has a fence. **Note** Fencing is a noun meaning Fences [enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fencing)

**Wrong**: They understand the personality of their children **Plural + Singular** **This cannot be split down** as each child has its own personality. The personality is not common to the group.

Correct: They understand the personalities of each of their children **Plural + Plural** This can be split down as each child has its own personality

**Wrong**: There were four rooms, each with a wonderful view of the garden ***Plural + Singular*** **This cannot be split down** as each room  has its own unique view, not a common view.

Correct: There were four rooms, each with wonderful views of the garden. **Plural + Plural** This can be split down as each room  has its own view.

Comment: Thanks, It makes a sense for me, but I need more references because native English speakers disagree with each other about this. I need official link from Cambridge or something that include your analysis.

Comment: I have Edited the Answer to include the Link

Comment: @Brad , you have written "Each of the buildings is surrounded by high metal fencing. Plural + Plural" .  This is slightly unclear, because fencing is not a standard plural. Usually plurals end with an -s (cars,  boats, sandwiches, etc). Right? It would be helpful to demonstrate the point with regular plurals - for example, would you say that "Each of the buildings is surrounded by high metal fences" is correct?

Comment: Well yes of course. but you cannot do that because it says fencing, not fences. However fencing  is a noun fencing
noun [ U ] UK ​  /ˈfen.sɪŋ/ US ​  /ˈfen.sɪŋ/
fencing noun [ U ] (STRUCTURE)
​fences, or the materials used to make fences: I will edit my answer.

Comment: I find this answer confusing. *personalities of each of their children* reads as *each of their children has personalities* to me, sounding like each child has multiple personalities. *They understand the personalities of their children* would be correct without the *each* as then you really do have plural+plural

Comment: Hi Brad, welcome and thanks for the contribution!   The website munged a couple of your links and your answer includes the words "link description" -- you can easily fix this by hitting the Edit button below your answer.  Thanks and keep contributing!